# WebM on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, video-playback, webm

What options are there for playing WebM video files on Mac OS X *other than VLC*? A plugin to Quicktime Player would be perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Perian](http://www.perian.org/), a QuickTime plugin should support WebM since version 1.2.2 according to their website.

[image]

Comment: I have Perian 1.2.3 and Quicktime Player 10.1 on OS X Lion fails to open `.webm` files with an error message.

Comment: Could be, I've never tried it. It may be that WebM is a mess of formats and containers as other formats before ir and Perian supports some but not all of them.

Comment: Judging from the Wikipedia article, it seems rather well defined. Still, +1 because *someone* apparently got it working, otherwise it wouldn't be in Perian.

Comment: Works for me too, with Perian 1.2.3. Added evidence to the answer ;) @dan

Comment: The problem may be QuickTime X in Lion.  [Possible Link](http://forums.cocoaforge.com/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=23700)

Comment: @lupincho can you please take a look at this post? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/134990/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-play-webm-in-safari-perian-doesnt-work?stw=2 Perian didn't work for me :(

Comment: WebM's may be different. Perian allows QuickTime Player to open now obsolete **VP8** encoded WebM files, but it doesn't enable it to play modern **VP9** WebM's.

Answer (score 4):

Not really much to choose from on macOS. While Perian is indeed VP8-capable, to play modern VP9 WebM's you may try minimalistic [mpv](http://mpv.io/) player.

On the second thought, you may not need a dedicated video player for any WebM at all, just open the file with any recent version of Firefox, Chrome, Opera or Safari and watch the video.